# Is the error with this w3schools javascript example, or is it with me?

Tags: javascript

[DOM HTMLCollection example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_htmlcollection_loop)

I think I grasp most of what's going on in that script, but its function doesn't seem to be accurately reflected in the results. I.e., it seems to be reporting the "head" tag in error. The only thing I can figure (other than the page being broken) is that head tags are somehow assumed to be present because "head is required" according to my quick web search, and somewhere along the way it's being inserted, somehow.

Sorry for what is probably a dumb question...

Comment: You’re right. HTML is quite fault tolerant. It fixes error in incomplete/incorrect documents by inserting necessary elements, or ignoring excessive ones.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick answer hackape.